# How to create a form for a has_many through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, has-many

In my app i have an index page of books from a Books Model. Think of it as a library.

Now i have Boards that consist of lists. Lets say i have a board called Categories.

So i go to the Categories Board. In my url it is www.example.com/board/1

On this categories board there are many lists. Lets say i have a list called programming books.

So now i need to add books to this list called Programming Books.

I have everything setup i just don't know how to add the books to the list. When i click the add books how do i get that list_id? I want to be able to click add books then it goes to a page that lists all the books. I then want to select the books by checking each one then add them to the list.

Don't worry about the creating the lists or boards i have that setup correctly i am just trying to add books to a list.

**Categories Board (www.example.com/board/1)**

```
===================     ===================     
=Programming Books=     =Adventure Books  =
===================     ===================
= Book 1          =     = add books       =
= Book 2          =     =                 =
= Book 3          =     =                 =
= add books       =     =                 =
===================     ===================
```

**List Model**

```
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :list

has_many :list_books
has_many :books, through: :list_books

accepts_nested_attributes_for :list_books, :allow_destroy => true
```

**List_Books Model**

```
belongs_to :list
belongs_to :books
```

**Book Model**

```
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :books

has_many :list_books
has_many :lists, through: :list_books

accepts_nested_attributes_for :list_books, :allow_destroy => true
```

**List Controller**

```
def addbooks
  // Not sure what to put here? It needs to grab the list_id from the list where i clicked add books.
end

private
  def_params
    // Not sure what params i need
  end
```

**AddBooks View**

```
// i need of list of all the books here. Then i want to check each book i want and then submit.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to handle it in a seperate action, just the regular create action and add `accept_nest_attributes` as in this example

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :classifications, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true , :inverse_of => :book accepts_nested_attributes_for :classifications, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank 
    has_many :categories, :through => :classifications 
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :classifications, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true , :inverse_of => :category accepts_nested_attributes_for :classifications, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank 
  has_many :books, :through => :classifications 
end


class Classification < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :category, :inverse_of => :classifications 
  belongs_to :book, :inverse_of => :classifications 
end
```

and then add it in your view.

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>

 <p>
 <%= f.label :name %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </p>

 <p>Categories</p>
 <ul>
 <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag "book_category_ids_none", nil, {:name => "book[category_ids][]"}%>
 <li>
 <%= check_box_tag "book_category_ids_#{cat.id}", cat.id, (f.object.categories.present? && f.object.categories.include?(cat.id)), {:name => "book[category_ids][]"} %>
 <%= label_tag "book_category_ids_#{cat.id}", cat.name %>
 </li>
 <% end %>
 </ul>

 <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

check full example [here](http://belighted.com/en/blog/how-to-handle-many-to-many-associations-in-nested-forms-using-checkboxes)

Comment: That actually won't work you see i have many boards that consist of lists. Like one board might be called Action Books with sub genres of lists. Then another board might be called Education Books with sub genres of lists. I need to get the list_id and add the books that way. Kinda of like a music library and playlists how you add songs from your library to playlists. These lists are like playlists and the books are the library.